# My simple method is not returning anything

Tags: java, methods

I have a simple assignment in which I create 10 methods. The first three work because there are no return variables (I just have to print things), but all of the methods that have return values are not returning anything.

Here is an example of one. Also, I do not have to actually call the methods for the assignment, I only added that as a test.

```
    public class Assignment05 {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
    
           displayGreeting();
           displayText("hello");
           printTotal(2,4,6);
    
           getTotal(2,4,6);
        }

        static void displayGreeting() 
        { 
            System.out.println("Hello, and Welcome!");
        }

        static void displayText(String text)
        {
            System.out.println(text);
        }

        static void printTotal(int one, int two, int three)
        {
            System.out.println(one + two + three);
        }

        static int getTotal(int one, int two, int three)
        {
    
            return one + two + three;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Where are you calling the getTotal() method from? Can you post the full class here?

Comment: I posted the full class.. The first three methods print correctly, but the getTotal one does not.

Comment: @mad just print the reuslt of the call to getTotal

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean that the output is not printed?

Try this:

`System.out.println(getTotal(2,4,6));`.

Comment: So the method on its own is correct? I do not have to call the methods in my assignment only create them.

Comment: Yes the method is correct, it returns the sum.
However without either printing the output, or debugging, or testing in some way (e.g. via JUnit) you won't be able to see (or prove) that the output of your method is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

> but all of the methods that have return values are not returning
> anything.

You not printing the returned value, of course it doesn't print anything out.

Try this:

```
int num = getTotal(2,4,6);
System.out.print(num);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method seems to be correct. But as others already mentioned if you want to see it, you need to print it. If you need to work further with the returned value, you also need to store it in a variable (or you could call the function every time you need the value, but that would be inefficient).

Answer (score 0):

Your should add `System.out.println` for the `getTotal()` function:

```
public class Assignment05 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       displayGreeting();
       displayText("hello");
       printTotal(2,4,6);

       System.out.println(getTotal(2,4,6));
    }

    static void displayGreeting() { 
        System.out.println("Hello, and Welcome!");
    }

    static void displayText(String text) {
        System.out.println(text);
    }

    static void printTotal(int one, int two, int three) {
        System.out.println(one + two + three);
    }

    static int getTotal(int one, int two, int three) {

        return one + two + three;
    }

}
```